# нужно ли обособлять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В 1999 году, перед лицом беспощадных испытаний, она покончила с собой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*В 1999 году, **перед лицом беспощадных испытаний**, она покончила с собой.*

Это **актуализация** обстоятельственного оборота на основе существительного. Оборот имеет значение **причины.**

**Пояснение**

1. В общем случае обособление **факультативное** по правилу [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114).

Пункт 1. Для **смыслового** выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.

2. При отсутствии обособления **неоднородные** отношения двух обстоятельств (времени и причины) в предложении такой структуры будут выглядеть некорректно, так как оборот имеет **высокую стилистику.**